# ASP.NET MVC Problem with validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this simple controller:

```
public class OneController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(IList<TestModel> m)
    {
        return View(m);
    }
}
```

And a very simple view with two objects of type TestModel, properly indexed.
When I submit the form with invalid data, I get the view with the errors highlighted.
However, when I re-submit it (without changing anything), I get this error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.UpdateCollection(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext, Type itemType) +612
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModelCore(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +519
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext) +829
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ParameterInfo
>   parameterInfo) +313
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(MethodInfo
>   methodInfo) +399
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +232
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +152
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +86
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +332
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +55
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) +28
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +358
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +64

Any idea on how can I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was already looking at that article, and found the bug I was having (subtle, yet critical).
If you render the hidden field with the index using Html.Hidden, the helper will "accumulate" the previous values, so you'll end up with a hidden saying index=1, and the next saying index=1,2.

Changing the helper call to a manually coded hidden field fixed the issue.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for posting your solution, I'll bet it'll help others who run across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I can answer without seeing more of the code and how your form is setup.
But, you could take a look at [Phil Haack's](http://www.haacked.com) blog entry about [Model Binding To A List](http://www.haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks that fixed it!

I replaced

```
<%= Html.Hidden("submitFormFields.index", controlID) %>
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitFormFields.index" name="submitFormFields.index" value="<%=controlID %>" />
```

Should we report this as a bug - It would be nice to have it fixed for ASP.Net MVC RC1

Comment: Hmm, still a problem in MVC 4